# Is there any Vanilla ICS ROM for Galaxy Note?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-note

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Is there a plain ICS ROM for the Samsung Galaxy Note? I'm looking for something that is relatively stable and without any kind of mods/frills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XDA Developers have published on May 10, 2012 an article regarding the update of GB ROM to ICS:

[International Galaxy Note Official ICS Released, Repackaged](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/international-galaxy-note-official-ics-released-repackaged/)

If you’re looking to install an ICS AOSP ROM on your Note, there's an article published on April 24, 2012:

[Get AOSP ICS ROMs on the Galaxy Note the Easy and Safe Way](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/get-aosp-ics-roms-on-the-galaxy-note-the-easy-and-safe-way/)

On both you'll find the step by step guides, links for the necessary files, the XDA forum thread with user comments and experiences about those two updates.

Comment: The "International Galaxy Note Official ICS" seems to be the ICS ROM with the TouchWiz. Am I correct? I'm looking for the one without the TouchWiz bloatware. How stable are these AOSP ROMS? I mean, do these ROMs have issues with the baseband, the drivers, etc.?

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla the vanilla AOSP that you can download and build are quite stable, but that's depending on where you get the source for kernel, the libs etc, which is beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla, as t0mm13b mentioned, it all depends from where you download them! As for XDA-Developers, they tend to know what they are doing, relying on users feedback to close or keep opened a forum thread! So, If the thread is still open, and comments reveal a positive experience, I'll say they are safe enough :)